# Telerik Master Server binding and Child Ajax binding?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

From the documentation I see that it says if the master is ajax or web service, the details must be ajax or web service.

If the Master is Server bound, can the children be ajax? I have view pages that are rendered by the model. If a user wants to drill into the data, I want to make an ajax call. Is that possible?

Right now when I try it with master server bound and child ajax, the Ajax call is never made. With Firebug, I can see no HTTP call is made.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the binding mode is inherited in the hierarchy, i.e. the master expand mode will be applied on the inner levels.

Comment: Apparently, this is not true. Looks like if the master is ajax or web service, the details must also ajax or web service. But if the master is server bound, the details can be ajax or web service: see http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/master-server-binding-and-child-ajax-binding.aspx